# WPF bug? Applying UnsetValue to the Foreground property in Hyperlinks

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I'm currently working on a highlightable richtextbox control in WPF. The user can type some text into a search box and the richtextbox is highlighting the occurences of the searched word. 
Everything works fine until I have hyperlinks in the richtextbox, for example:

```
blablabla stackoverflow.com
```

And I search for the term:

```
st
```

It highlights the text ("st" in stackoverflow) correctly with a red foreground.
But when I'm pressing a backspace - so the search term becomes the single "s" letter -, I get an exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'NamedObject' parameter type is not valid for formatting property 'Foreground'.
Parameter name: value
```

This is because my algorithm is looks like this:

1. Highlight the text in the richtextbox: I add every highlighted TextRange to a Dictionary, where the key is the highlighted TextRange, and the value is the old foreground property of that TextRange which I retrieve with this code:

   ```
   textrange.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty)
   ```
2. Every time a user changes the filter string, I delete the old highlighting and I "re-highlight" the richtextbox with the new filter string like in Step 1.

   - The exception comes from the "delete the highlighting" part of the process. To delete the highlighting, I enumerate the Dictionary, and for every TextRange I reset the ForegroundProperty to the saved value:

     ```
     foreach (var textRangeEntry in highlightedTexts)
     {                
         textRangeEntry.Key.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, textRangeEntry.Value);
     }
     ```

The problem is that sometimes the saved ForegroundProperty becomes a DependencyProperty.UnsetValue - and I get an exception.

Which is strange. It looks like the ForegroundProperty "doesn't like" the UnsetValue, but for example, when I filter to

```
ov
```

in the text

```
blablabla stackoverflow.com
```

and then when I'm erasing the "v", everything's OK.

The exception only comes out when I'm highlighting the beginning of hyperlinks.

Is it a strange bug in WPF or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that this problem (bug?) is inside the textrange.GetPropertyValue call. I will repost this question in a shorter and a more specific form.

Comment: I reposted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668598/wpf-bug-textrange-getpropertyvalue-in-richtextbox