# WPF bug: TextRange.GetPropertyValue in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have to retrieve the Foreground property of the selected text in a WPF RichtTextBox, but I think, there is a bug in the TextRange.GetPropertyValue function.
I've written a simple application to test the error:

```
   <RichTextBox x:Name="rtfBox">
        <RichTextBox.Document>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run>run run run</Run>
                    <Hyperlink TargetName="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</Hyperlink>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox.Document>
    </RichTextBox>
    <Button Content="Click!" Height="28" Click="Button_Click" />
```

And in the code behind:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textrange = new TextRange(rtfBox.Selection.Start, rtfBox.Selection.End);
        var propertyValue = textrange.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty);
        MessageBox.Show(propertyValue.ToString());
    }
```

When I select the first few characters of the stackoverflow hyperlink, the MessageBox says that the Foreground property is a DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, but when I select other parts of the link, it shows the true foreground color.

It looks like a bug.

Are there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the TextElement.ForegroundProperty.
If you change it to `Hyperlink.ForegroundProperty`, it will show the true value.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that, but it's not working for me. Everything is the same.

Comment: It's not working only if you select a part from both. (For example "run run stackoverfl").

Comment: No, it's not working if you select "st" from stackoverflow. Have you tried out?

Comment: And it's strange because if I select "s", it says that it's black (but it's not, only the Run before that)
If I select the "t" (2nd letter from stackoverflow), it says the true Foreground brush color.
It looks like it "looks before" the selection somehow.
For example when you have a one-lettered hyperlink, like this:
<Hyperlink TargetName="http://stackoverflow.com">B</Hyperlink>

....then there is no way to select the true foreground color!

Comment: :) I selected every time only the end of the link. You're right.